# Get Value of Iterable Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a list as shown below.
Now I want to get the values of each radio button when clicking on it. However, I get always the first value since the IDs (list-name) will be the same when rendered out the list.

Is there a simple way to do so? Maybe with `onclick=function(this)`

```
<form id="form-1">
{% for u in user %}
  <li>
    <div>
       <input id="list-name" type="radio" value="{{ u.name }}" name="list-radio">
       <label for="list-name">{{ u }}, {{ u.name }}</label>
    </div>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</form>



<script>
    $(document).on('change', '#form-1', function (e){
      console.log($('#list-name').val())
    }
</script>
```

Comment: FYI. LI is not a valid immediate child of FORM

Answer (score 1):

The attribute [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) is unique in a document. Use [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead. Also use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword to refer the currently clicked element.

**Updated Code:**

```
<form id="form-1">
  {% for u in user %}
    <li>
      <div>
         <input class="list-name" type="radio" value="{{ u.name }}" name="list-radio">
         <label for="list-{{ u.name }}">{{ u }}, {{ u.name }}</label>
      </div>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</form>

<script>
    $(document).on('change', '.list-name', function (e){
      console.log($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

**Demo:**

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>

<form id="form-1">
  <li>
    <div>
       <input class="list-name" type="radio" value="John" name="list-radio" id="list-John">
       <label for="list-John">User 1, John</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
       <input class="list-name" type="radio" value="Jane" name="list-radio" id="list-Jane">
       <label for="list-Jane">User 2, Jane</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  
</form>

<script>
    $(document).on('change', '.list-name', function (e){
      console.log($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that these are radio buttons that at grouped by their name you can get the current value of the radioNodeList by its name on the form (`form.list_radio.value`).

Don't use hyphens in id or name values. If you feel like it, use underscore instead.

```js
document.forms.form_1.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  console.log(form.list_radio.value);
});
```

```html
<form id="form_1">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="list_radio">Item 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label><input type="radio" value="2" name="list_radio">Item 2</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```